# Can I restore a blockchain.info wallet into a electrum wallet?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery

If I have a blockchain.info wallet, I got the 12 words. Can I use these 12 words to restore into a new Electrum wallet?

After that, will the blockchain wallet still operational? Say, can it still receive funds or spend fund? If fund is received/spent, will it appear in the new Electrum wallet?

On the other hand, if I send fund / receive fund in the new Electrum wallet, will those transaction appear in the blockchain.info wallet?

Answer (score 2):

In Electrum:

1. Click **File** > **New/Restore**, enter a name and click **Next**.
2. Select **Standard Wallet** and then **Next**.
3. Select **I already have a seed** and then **Next**.
4. Enter the 12 words seed you got from blockchain.info (from *Settings* > *Security* > *Backup phrase*.
5. Click the "Options" button and enable BIP39.
6. Accept the default derivation key and click **Next**.
7. In the next step, set a wallet password and enable encryption.

Now you have your wallet imported.

> if I send fund / receive fund in the new Electrum wallet, will those transaction appear in the blockchain.info wallet?

Yes, they will.

Comment: Make sure to set correct derivation as you may have multiple wallets https://blog.blockonomics.co/how-to-restore-blockchain-com-wallet-into-electrum-f593ec79ab3d